# IBM Containers open ports

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

When I bind an app on IBM Containers to external IP, looks like only 22 (ssh), 80, 443(http/https) and port range 8000-9500 are open. Is this correct ?  I believe private network has no restriction, only applies to external network.

I've confirmed this by changing the port of Node.js like

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var server = app.listen(port, function ()
```

And run like:

```
# PORT=8080 node app.js
```

And then curl external IP like:

```
$ curl <external-ip>:8080
```

And changed the port from 8000 to several ranges, and found 9500 is final port number which I can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons there is a limited set of ports opened that can be accessed externally. The range you mentioned is not necessarily correct and the list is not published externally for security reasons as well.

If you need a port to be opened for your specific application you can open a support ticket with the Bluemix support team:

ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

Comment: Thank for the answer. I understand about publication for security reason.

Comment: How does not publishing the list of ports make anything more secure?  It is a major negative for usability!  Hoping this policy gets revised in the near future -- possibly with a firewall service a la AWS.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation is no longer in place! All new Bluemix spaces that use Containers will have the ability to expose ANY port selected at container creation time. Hooray progress!

See the public ports section under:

UI: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_single_ui

or

CLI: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_single_cli

Oh, note that this is now using Network Security Groups under the covers much like other cloud providers use so that we get flexibility and security.